# Vscode no detecta el kernel para usar Python en Jupyter notebook

Tags: vscode, jupyter

Estoy intentando abrir mis jupyter notebooks en vscode. Ya lo he hecho en el pasado, pero desde hace algun tiempo el vscode no detecta el kernel y no puedo correr la celdas de codigo.

[image: Aca una imagen de referencia]

Python esta instalado y el path en las variables de entorno. Ademas Jupyter Notebook esta instalado:

[image: Jupyter Notebook instalado]

Las extensiones de jupyter tambien:

[image: Extensiones instaladas]

Ya intente forzar la reinstalacion:
[image: force reinstall]

Comment: No tendrás alguna variable mal escrita en el PATH?

Comment: Muchas gracias por intestar contestar amigo. Ya revise el PATH muchas veces, en las variables de entorno. De hecho, los otros archivos "*.py" los puedo correr sin problemas. El problema lo tengo es con los jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Si puedes acceder a ellos desde el CMD (fuera de VS Code)? También checa cuales agregaste al PATH, agrega tanto las que estén en `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming` como en `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local`.

Comment: Quisiera saber si se pudo solucionar este problema. A mí me sucede algo similar, cuando intento solicitar un input se queda conectando con el Kernel y nunca ejecuta el código. Cuando lo ejecuto en ".py" sí los ejecuta sin problema.